# Assign Value to String Function Argument? (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino, arguments

I'm attempting to understand what the proper way to assign a value to a String function argument in Arduino.

Let's say I have the following testing code:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  String str;
  bool res = TEST(str);
  Serial.println("res: " + String(res));
  Serial.println("str: " + str);

  delay(1000);
}

bool TEST(String str)
{
  str = "TEST";
  return true;
}
```

In the code above, I want the `str` local variable defined inside the `loop` function to attain a value of `"TEST"` upon every call to the `TEST` function.
However, I want the `TEST` function to return a boolean, which is assigned to the local variable `res`, and for my String variable `str` to be assigned it's value of `"TEST"` inside the `TEST` function by modifying the argument.

The code above currently outputs the following to the Serial Monitor:

```
res: 1
str:
```

And I would like for the output to be the following:

```
res: 1
str: TEST
```

I guess I'm misunderstanding how value assignments to function arguments work. Is that only possible if the function argument is a pointer?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: maybe split TEST() into 2 functions, one which returns a string and one which returns a boolean. or you could use pointers. i still do not understand why you want to this instead of just printing "res: 1\nstr: TEST" in loop. I'll write an answer that uses pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a parameter to a function is copied by value.  Any changes you make to it are local to the function and stay within the function.

To change this you can pass by *reference*:

```
bool TEST(String &str)
//               ^
{
  str = "TEST";
  return true;
}
```

Yes you could use a pointer, but that's old-fashioned C style coding.